# How do I factorise this polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help factorise this: 
$$6x^2+x+4=0$$

In my attempts, I assumed $a=6$, $b=1$ and $c=4$.

I multiplied $c$ by $a$ and attempted to get the factors that give us the sum of $b$.

The only factor pairs of $24$ are $1\cdot 24$, $2\cdot 12$, $3\cdot 8$ and $4\cdot 6$.

None of the above can give me a sum of $1$.

Comment: I think you cannot factorize it in real numbers

Comment: L. Xu is correct. A quick look into wolfram alpha (or simply applying the quadratic formula) shows that the roots of this polynomial are complex, and not particularly nice either. What is the goal of this problem? Is it possible there is a typo somewhere?

Comment: I found this in an exam paper. The actual question reads "Solve the following equation". Probably this is not the best way to solve it?

Comment: Indeed. I would use the quadratic formula if you are familiar with it. This equation has complex roots and would likely be very hard to factor just by looking at it.

Comment: $24$ also has factors $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Your approach is in the spirit of the rational root theorem, which is often (but not always) successful.  The rational root theorem says the roots could be $\frac {factors of 4}{factors of 6}$ so you should check $\frac 23$ and others, not factors of $24$.  As others have shown, this fails in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Let us complete the square:

\begin{align*}
6 x^2 + x + 4 &= 6 \left(x^2 + \frac{1}{6} x + \frac{3}{2}\right) \\
&= 6 \left(x^2 + \frac{1}{6} x + \frac{1}{144} + \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{144}\right) \\
&= 6 \left(x + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + 6 \left(\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{144}\right) \\
&= 6 \left(x + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 + \left(9 - \frac{1}{24}\right)
\end{align*}

Setting this to zero gives

$$6 \left(x + \frac{1}{12}\right)^2 = - \left(9 - \frac{1}{24}\right) < 0$$

which has no real solutions.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the quadratic formula

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
As $$ x  = \frac{(-1)\pm \sqrt{-95}}{12},$$
you will not get real roots.

Comment: @dfeuer: thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem. Just try to learn from the changes if you can. You can click the edit button to see the new source.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to determine whether a given quadratic polynomial will have real roots, and that is by using the [*discriminant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

For some polynomial $\mathcal{P} = ax^2 + bx + c$ then the discriminant $\Delta$ of $\mathcal{P}$ is defined as
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$$

The discriminant provides the following information:

- For $\Delta$ > 0, there are two real roots
- For $\Delta$ = 0, there is exactly one real root
- For $\Delta$ < 0, there are no real roots

In this case we have $\mathcal{P} = 6x^2+x+4=0$, so

$$\Delta = (1)^2 - 4(6)(4) = -95 < 0$$

Therefore there are no real roots. Furthermore, this makes $\mathcal{P}$ an [irreducible polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) of order 2. So, the factored form is simply itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the box method. ac = 24; so I need to find factors of 24 that add up to 1. Thus, I have no factors, and it is irreducible.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer doesn't make much sense to me. What is the box method? Regardless, simply using the quadratic formula gives the roots quickly and shows that this polynomial doesn't factor over the rationals or the reals.